# Typescript error when using generic T extends Type on container class but not with direct reference to Type

Tags: typescript, generics, extends

in the following code, if I use `T extends HealthyConfig` and create a `Config` class instance using the generic `T` I get an error of `Type 'boolean' does not satisfy the constraint 'T[keyof T]'`, but when directly referencing `HealthyConfig` no error is displayed. Surely because `T` extends `HealthyConfig` the types should be known as far as at least those defined in `HealthyConfig` so why doesn't it work with using `T`?

```js
type Key = string | number;
type Val = Key | boolean | Obj;
type Obj = { [x: Key]: Val } | Array<Val>;

interface Config<T extends Obj> {
    get<Tret extends T[keyof T]>(key: keyof T, defaultVal: Tret): Tret;
}

type EnabledConfig = {
    enabled?: boolean;
}

class Enabled<T extends EnabledConfig> implements Config<T> {
    public readonly c: T;
    constructor(c?: T) {
        this.c = c || {} as T;
    }
    
    get<Tret extends T[keyof T]>(key: keyof T, defaultVal: Tret): Tret {
        const result: Tret = this.c[key] as Tret;
        return (result === undefined) ? defaultVal : result;
    }
}

type Status = 'yes' | 'no';

type HealthyConfig = EnabledConfig & {
    healthy?: Status;
}

class Healthy {
    public readonly config: Config<HealthyConfig>
    constructor(config: Config<HealthyConfig>) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    get enabled(): boolean {
        return this.config.get<boolean>('enabled', true);
    }
}

const en = new Enabled<HealthyConfig>({enabled: false});
const isEnabled: boolean = en.get<boolean>('enabled', true); // works
const isHealthy: Status = en.get<Status>('healthy', 'no'); // works

const h = new Healthy(new Enabled<HealthyConfig>({enabled: true, healthy: 'no'}));
const enabled: boolean = h.config.get<boolean>('enabled', true); // works
const healthy: Status = h.config.get<Status>('healthy', 'yes'); // works

// This generic "T extends HealthyConfig" causes a problem 
// with the "this.config.get" showing an error on the "<boolean>"
// of "Type 'boolean' does not satisfy the constraint 'T[keyof T]'"
class UnHealthy<T extends HealthyConfig> {
    public readonly config: Config<T>
    constructor(config: Config<T>) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    get enabled(): boolean {
        return this.config.get<boolean>('enabled', true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a little refactor of your code:

```js
type Key = string | number;
type Val = Key | boolean | Obj;
type Obj = { [x: Key]: Val } | Array<Val>;

interface Config<T extends Obj> {
    get<K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(key: K, defaultVal: V): V;
}

type EnabledConfig = {
    enabled?: boolean;
}

class Enabled<T extends EnabledConfig> implements Config<T> {
    public readonly c: T;
    constructor(c?: T) {
        this.c = c || {} as T;
    }
    
    get<K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(key: K, defaultVal: V): V {
        const result: V = this.c[key] as V;
        return (result === undefined) ? defaultVal : result;
    }
}

type Status = 'yes' | 'no';

type HealthyConfig = EnabledConfig & {
    healthy?: Status;
}

class Healthy {
    public readonly config: Config<HealthyConfig>
    constructor(config: Config<HealthyConfig>) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    get enabled() {
        return this.config.get('enabled', true);
    }
}

const en = new Enabled<HealthyConfig>({enabled: false});
const isEnabled: boolean = en.get('enabled', true); // works
const isHealthy: Status = en.get('healthy', 'no'); // works

const h = new Healthy(new Enabled<HealthyConfig>({enabled: true, healthy: 'no'}));
const enabled: boolean = h.config.get('enabled', true); // works
const healthy: Status = h.config.get('healthy', 'yes'); // works

// This generic "T extends HealthyConfig" causes a problem 
// with the "this.config.get" showing an error on the "<boolean>"
// of "Type 'boolean' does not satisfy the constraint 'T[keyof T]'"
class UnHealthy<T extends Config<HealthyConfig>> {
    public readonly config: T
    constructor(config: T) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    get enabled() {
        return this.config.get('enabled', true);
    }
}
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: this is it! thanks for fixing this... was driving me crazy. I see I was expecting too much in the recursion and your fix makes sense as it simplifies the lookups and still solves for what I wanted to accomplish. Thanks again!

Comment: Beware all that `V extends T[K]` means that whatever possibly-narrower type is entered as `defaultVal()` is definitely going to come out of `get()`, which is not true by the implementation.  See [this example](https://tsplay.dev/Wyel6W) where the compiler thinks a `number` is coming out when it's really a `string`.  The assertion `this.c[key] as V` is the issue.  Of course the same thing happens with the original code, so this isn't any worse, really.

Comment: @jcalz that's a fair point, but my goal was to scope the possible keys to only the specified `XYZConfig` object keys and to see, in the intellisense, the possible values / value types and I'm able to get that now so I'd say this is a success

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need UnHealthy to be generic? Provide concrete config, HealthyConfig in your case, compiler will pick up T[keyof T], and you won't able to use type distinct from `boolean | Status | undefined` as the defaultVal arg.

```js
class UnHealthy {
    public readonly config: Config<HealthyConfig>
    constructor(config: Config<HealthyConfig>) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    get enabled() {
        console.log(this.config)
        return this.config.get('enabled', false)
    }
}
```

Comment: the `UnHealthy` class needs to use a Generic so that other classes that extend from it can set additional `XYZConfig` types to affect the scoping. if I were to lock in the scope to only `HealthyConfig` then any classes extending from `UnHealthy` can only use the keys and values specified in `HealthyConfig` and not add their own

Comment: Think I understood you, but its kinda complex to implement since TS couldn't unwrap T[keyof T] where config is generic also